# json creates additional attributes than my object

Tags: json, jackson

I have a class that has attributes A,B,C. I am using Jackson parser to convert my class object to JSON. But the Json output has additional attributes that are not members of the class. When and how does this happen?

```
Class MyClass{
public int A;
public int B;
public int C;
}
```

JSON resposne-
{"A": 1, "B": 2 , "C":3 , "some_extra" : 1, "some_extra2" : 2}

I am totally boggled as to how this happened.

Comment: You have additional public getters in your MyClass ?

Comment: No. the class literally has just those three attributes!

Comment: The some_extra have the same name as attributes A and B. i tried changing those attribute names in the class and the JSON response reflected those changes corresponding to A and B's names and some_extra1 and some_extra2 as well.

Comment: Sharing your class code (including methods) will be helpful.